# Why does my recyclerview crash when text changes quickly?

Tags: java, android, filter, android-recyclerview

I have a simple app setup where a user can search for a products name or sku, and from there it will automatically change a recyclerview on query change. However, if the text changes too quickly, the app crashes.

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 0(offset:0).state:128 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`

I have already tried running it on the UI thread, on the same thread as the view, and shrinking the viewholder to something far more simple but it still does not work. Interestingly enough, this error does not occur when in landscape mode.

Here is the code for my filter:

```
    public Filter getFilter(){
        return new Filter(){
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence){
                String searchString = charSequence.toString();
                if(searchString.isEmpty()){
                    filteredProducts.clear();
                }
                else{
                   List<Product> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                   Log.d("Product List Size","" + ProductUtil.allProducts.size());
                   for(Product product : ProductUtil.allProducts){
                       if(product.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())){
                           filteredList.add(product);
                       }
                       else if(product.getCategory().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())){
                           filteredList.add(product);
                       }
                       else if(product.getSku().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())){
                           filteredList.add(product);
                       }
                       else if(product.getSku().toLowerCase().replace("-", "").contains(searchString.toLowerCase())){
                           filteredList.add(product);
                       }


                   }
                   filteredProducts = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = filteredProducts;
                return filterResults;

            }
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence sequence, FilterResults filterResults){
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

In landscape, this works fine and the filter changes as soon as the query for the search changes. However in portrait, if the text changes too quick it fails.

EDIT:
Here is the entire adapter code:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private List<Product> filteredProducts;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Database database;
    private Context context;
    private String pi_ip;
    public boolean isClickable = true;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context){
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        filteredProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        database = Room.databaseBuilder(context, Database.class, "Settings_DB").allowMainThreadQueries().fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
        try{
        Settings ipsetting = database.settingInterface().getSetting("pi_ip");
        pi_ip = ipsetting.getSettingValue();}
        catch (Exception e){
            pi_ip = "127.0.0.1";
        }
    }

    public void newProducts(){
        filteredProducts.clear();
        for(Product product : ProductUtil.allProducts){
            if(product.isNewProduct()){
                filteredProducts.add(product);
            }



        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void bestSellers(){
        filteredProducts.clear();
        for(Product product : ProductUtil.allProducts){
            if(product.isBestSeller()){
                filteredProducts.add(product);
            }



        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.product, parent, false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(mItemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Product mCurrent = filteredProducts.get(position);
        holder.productName.setText(mCurrent.getName());
        if(mCurrent.getShotCount() > 0){
            holder.productPrice.setText(mCurrent.getShotCount() + " Shot");
        }
        else{
            holder.productPrice.setText("");
        }
        holder.productSKU.setText(mCurrent.getSku());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isClickable) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoPlayer.class);
                    intent.putExtra("item", mCurrent.getSku().toLowerCase().replace("-",""));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filteredProducts.size();
    }

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public final TextView productName;
        final ProductAdapter mAdapter;
        public final TextView productPrice;
        public final TextView productSKU;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView, ProductAdapter adapter){
            super(itemView);
            productName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
            this.mAdapter = adapter;
            productPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productPrice);
            productSKU = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productSKU);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter(){
        return new Filter(){
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence){
                String searchString = charSequence.toString();
                if(searchString.isEmpty()){
                    filteredProducts.clear();
                }
                else{
                   List<Product> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                   Log.d("Product List Size","" + ProductUtil.allProducts.size());
                   for(Product product : ProductUtil.allProducts){
                       if(product.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())){
                           filteredList.add(product);
                       }
                       else if(product.getCategory().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())){
                           filteredList.add(product);
                       }
                       else if(product.getSku().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())){
                           filteredList.add(product);
                       }
                       else if(product.getSku().toLowerCase().replace("-", "").contains(searchString.toLowerCase())){
                           filteredList.add(product);
                       }


                   }
                   filteredProducts = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = filteredProducts;
                return filterResults;

            }
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence sequence, FilterResults filterResults){
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the adapter code

Comment: I edited it into the original post.